# Unreal 4 C++ Actor Movement

Tags: c++, animation, unreal-engine4

I have data for an actors movement which is being read in from a file at the start of the game. The data that gets read in contains Vector positions where the Actor should move to next. I currently have the Actor moving from Position to Position no problem... until I start to add animation to a Skeletal Mesh attached to the Actor.

My problem: How can I found out the velocity to work out which animation to play idle, walk, jog and running? It currently doesnt have a velocity as i am lerping the position:

SetActorLocation(FMath::Lerp(GetActorLocation(), newPos, 0.01));

Any thoughts on how to set the right animation based on distance travel and speed?

Should I move my Actors movement to Character so I can use AddMovementInput to get velocity. Then, If i go down that route, how to I say:

Move this character from my current position, to my next position in X amount of time giving the character the correct velocity to use in the animation selection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you normalize the difference between the two vector lengths (GetWorldLocation) and use the abs(floating point) result as the X variable to put into 1D Blend Space to do idle, walk, jog, run in your Animation BP? Also be sure to account for an "acceptance radius" or else once it gets to location it won't quite get it and keep turning quickly.

Not sure why you're Lerping from Vector to Vector. I would've personally used (MoveToActor or MoveToLocation):

```
AMyPawn->MoveToActor(AMyActor, 90.f,true,true,false,0,true);
```

So much cleaner! Also MoveToLocation, using BT/BB.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I have some questions:
Which class should I use as a base for my actor that is controlled by the data being read in? An Actor/Character/Pawn/ - and why?
What would be the best way to move that? Lerp location? MoveTo?

Comment: Def Pawn/Character.  I actually have an EnemyCharacter (AEnemyCharacter.h + cpp) class that inherits from ACharacter (Character.h + cpp) which is essentially inheriting from APawn (Pawn.h + cpp). Characters already have built in moving logic! They are responsible for all physical interaction between the player or AI and the world. You can directly channel the character movement component, and power the motor. You can use either MoveToLocation, MoveTo or Move Directly Toward. These are all available in your Behaviour Tree. You can also setup Blackboard with different enemy targets!